# For loop inside while loop not working in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am facing very unusual problem, below is code inside a class where `pitnamebasename` is 2d list.
For example:=
`pitnamebasename= [['a','b'],['n','m'],['b','c'],['m','f'],['c','d'],['d',''],['h','f']]`
Above list is not necessary to be in any order like `['d','']` can be at 0th order.

Here is my function (inside a class):-

```
   def getRole(self,pitname):
            basename=pitname
            print '\n\n\nbasename=',basename
            ind=True
            while pitname and ind:
                    ind=False
                    basename=pitname
                    print 'basename=',basename
                    for i in self.pitnamebasename:
                            print 'comparing-',i[0],'and',pitname
                            if i[0] == pitname:
                                    pitname=i[1]
                                    print 'newpitname=',pitname
                                    ind=True
                                    break
            print 'returning-',basename
            return basename
```

`pitname` is the string for example here it can be 'a'. I want return value to be 'd' mean the traversing must be like a to b, b to c and d to None, hence return value must be d.
Please don't suggest me any other methods to solve.
Now my problem is that in the for loop its not looping till last but getting out in middle. Like return value is either b or c or even d depends on what I am searching. Actually list is very very long. Strange thing I noted that for loop loops only to that index where it loops till its first time. Like here first time for loop gets end when it find 'a' and `pitname` becomes 'b' but when it search for 'b' it loops till it find 'a' only. Does anyone knows how it is happening?

Comment: `pitnamebasename` should probably be a `dict`.

Comment: @chepner agreed, O(1) lookup and much simpler/readable

Comment: can you post an example output. Especially if you see a "newpitname=..."

Comment: Are you certain that the very very long list doesn't contain any duplicates? If there are two different `['a', 'x']` values, then the chain might not complete, or you might get stuck in a loop.

Comment: why are you assigning the variable basename the same value pitname twice????

Comment: do you consider to use a debugger?

Comment: The behavior you describe suggests that your version of `pitnamebasename` contains both an `['a', 'b']` value and a `['b', 'a']` value. This algorithm will go into an infinite loop in that case. It will only work if it's guaranteed that the list has no cycles like that. You should read about [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory); `pitnamebasename` is a directed graph.

Comment: When I run your code it seems to work like expected for a, b, c, and d. They all return `d`.

Comment: Hi all people, I know other methods to solve the problem including use of dict. My actual problem is looping out in middle of this code.
@senderle - if ['a','b'] is present then ['b','a'] will not be present and it will never go in loop.

Please suggest why loop is getting out and this code doesnt work?

Comment: Sagar, I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "loop is getting out"? You need to make it easier for us to understand the problem you're having. Your current code behaves correctly for the input you gave, so there appears to be no problem for us to solve. I would _strongly_ suggest that you edit your question to show input values that show your problem, and tell us what output you expect. In other words, you should post code that we can paste into a text file and run, and immediately see the problem.

Comment: Hi @senderle, I found the problem, I thought that the inner loop is not getting completed and hence not getting my answer but actually there was a flaw in calling this function. I was adding new list in pitnamebasename and just after that I was calling this function mean adding and calling one after one was wrong. So the solution was to first fill the list completely and then call it to get desired result. So silly of me :(
Thanks all for alternate solution and giving your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
pitnamebasename= [['a','b'],['n','m'],['b','c'],['m','f'],['c','d'],['d',''],['h','f']]
```

First, change your '2d' array into a `dict`:

```
pitnamebasename = dict(pitnamebasename)
```

Now, it should be a simple matter of walking from element to element, using the value associated with the current key as the next key, until the value is the empty string; then
return the current key. If `pitname` ever fails to exist as a key, it's treated as if it does exist and maps to the empty string.

```
def getRole(self, pitname):
    while pitnamebasename.get('pitname', '') != '':
        pitname = pitnamebasename[pitname]
    return pitname
```

A `defaultdict` could also be used in this case:

```
import collections.defaultdict
pitnamebasename = defaultdict(str, pitnamebasename)
def getRole(self, pitname):
    while pitnamebasename[pitname] != '':
        pitname = pitnamebasename[pitname]
    return pitname
```

Comment: Not that I don't approve the use of a dict, but at first glance I'm thinking OP's code should work, too. Also "You don't specify what the behavior should be if a value of pitname is not found as a key in the dictionary." - looks like the while loop will terminate since `ind` is never becoming true again.

Comment: True; I'll take that as the expected behavior and update my answer.

Comment: @Ben, you're right, a dict won't solve the problem here because this does exactly what the original code does. The problem is (probably) that the algorithm can't deal with the specific data passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the solution to your problem but I am having trouble replicating the problem. This code does the same thing without requiring you to change your entire class storage system.

By converting your list of lists into a dictionary lookup (looks like the following)

```
as_list_of_lists = [['a','b'],['n','m'],['b','c'],['m','f'],['c','d'],['d',''],['h','f']]
as_dict = dict(as_list_of_lists)
# as_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'b': 'c', 'd': '', 'h': 'f', 'm': 'f', 'n': 'm'}
```

we can do a default dictionary lookup using the dictionary method .get. This will look for an item (say we pass it 'a') and return the associated value ('b'). If we look for something that isn't in the dictionary, .get will return the second value (a default value) which we can supply as ''. Hence as_dict.get('z','') will return ''

```
class this_class
    def __init__(self):
        self.pitnamebasename= [['a','b'],['n','m'],['b','c'],['m','f'],['c','d'],['d',''],['h','f']]

    def getRole(self,pitname):
        lookup = dict(self.pitnamebasename)
        new_pitname = pitname
        while new_pitname != '':
            pitname = new_pitname
            new_pitname = lookup.get(pitname, '')
        return pitname
```